# FLASK PYTHON - Difficulty with JavaScript/Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am currently trying to change the action of a form using javascript with Jinja2 from this:

```
 <form method="post" id="mainForm" onsubmit="return validateFormMultiple()" action="{{ url_for('questionsUserView2', page=page + 1,child_id=child_id, child_name=child_name, totalPage=pagination.get_page_count() + 1) }}" name="myForm" onsubmit="" onload="pagination()">
```

--To this:---

```
  var frm = document.getElementById("mainForm")
if(frm)
{
    frm.action = "{{ url_for('questionsUserView2', page=page - 1, child_id=child_id, child_name=child_name, totalPage=pagination.get_page_count() + 1) }}";


}
```

However, from my app.py file, this only updates the first variable(page) and returns all other values passed in the new action as "None." This doesn't happen if the form action attribute is not changed(all values are not none).

What's the best way to manipulate a jinja value specifically only using Javascript in a HTML view? Is there something wrong with the syntax here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just had to add the safe keyword `frm.action = "{{ url_for('questionsUserView2', child_id=child_id,page=page - 1,child_name=child_name,totalPage=pagination.get_page_count() + 1)|safe }}";`